# Get datasource from dropdownlist with JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the datasource of a dropdownlist in c# on the client side using javascript or JQuery. Do you know how to do it?

```
 <asp:DropDownList id="ddlList" runat="server" width="50%"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I fill in as in the following code:

```
if (!PostBack) {

this.ddlList.DataSource = CreateDataSource(this.List);
this.ddlList.DataTextField = "Name";
this.ddlList.DataValueField = "value";
this.ddlList.DataBind();


}

ICollection CreateDataSource(List<Vendor> vendorList)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsActive", typeof(bool)));

    foreach (var item in List)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(CreateRow(item.DisplayName, item.Value, item.IsActive, dt));
    }
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    return dv;
}


DataRow CreateRow(string Name, string Value, bool IsActive, DataTable dt)
{    
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                
    dr[0] = Name;
    dr[1] = Value;
    dr[2] = IsActive;

    return dr;
}
```

No problem to get the values on c# side this way but how to do in JS or Jquery?

```
var test = (DataView)this.ddlList.DataSource;
var test2 = test[i].Row["nameOfRow"]; //i is the index of the line
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The dropdownlist renders as a `select` tag in the browser, so yes, you can use javascript to access it like anything else in the document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I access the "is active" element in the dataSource? It is not the text or the value but a field of the datasource (dr[2] in the example above)

Comment: `IsActive` doesn't make it down to the browser, only the text and value bindings do. Inspect the element with the browser dev tools. When an option is selected it will have a `selected` attribute. The asp.net runtime will know what is selected when you submit the form but I can't remember exactly what that will look like in code behind.

Comment: "IsActive" is an attribute of my "datasource" inserted in my dropdownlist not the active element of my dropdownlist. We misunderstood each other

Comment: I understand IsActive is part of your data model but it does not get used in the generated html.

Comment: And do you know if there is a way to get it back? My goal is to modify a checkbox without refreshing the page according to the value of the IsActive of the item selected in the dropdownlist. Thanks again for your answers